# How to check running scheduler jobs in laravel 5.2 on live server?

Tags: laravel-5

How to check running scheduler or cron jobs in laravel 5.2 on the live server?
I want to know how to find running cron job in on my laravel project?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `jobs` table for this. If you do not have this table yet, then you can create it by running the following commands:

```
php artisan queue:table
```

```
php artisan migrate
```

and set your queue driver to `database` in `config/queue.php`. the created table will hold currently active jobs along with number of attempts.